# PySpark joining two data frames by closest time value

Tags: python-2.7, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames (tx_df and login_df).
First one has columns player_id, tx_id, and tx_time while second has player_id and login_time.

What I want to do is to join those two data frames using player_id column but in addition to that, to join only the latest login row from login_df.
For example, if there is tx_df like this:

```
pid_1, txid_1, '2016-11-16 00:01:00'
pid_1, txid_2, '2016-11-16 00:01:02'
pid_1, txid_3, '2016-11-16 00:02:15'
pid_1, txid_4, '2016-11-16 00:02:16'
pid_1, txid_5, '2016-11-16 00:02:17'
```

and login_df like this:

```
pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:02:10'
pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:00:55'
pid_1, '2016-11-13 00:03:00'
pid_1, '2016-11-10 16:30:00'
```

I want resulting data frame to look like this:

```
pid_1, txid_1, '2016-11-16 00:01:00', pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:00:55'
pid_1, txid_2, '2016-11-16 00:01:02', pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:00:55'
pid_1, txid_3, '2016-11-16 00:02:15', pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:02:10'
pid_1, txid_4, '2016-11-16 00:02:16', pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:02:10'
pid_1, txid_5, '2016-11-16 00:02:17', pid_1, '2016-11-16 00:02:10'
```

I am not mandatory bound to data frames, so a hint how to do it nicely using RDDs or any other approach will be appreciated.

Explosion of data is what I fear because tx_df can have thousands of transaction entries for every player id (and then thousands of player ids) while login_df can have also unknown number of player login information. Simply joining those two on player_id would create an enormous data frame as a result of cartesian product which is not acceptable.

NOTE: I am using Python API for Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a future reference, I managed to solve this with a slightly different approach.
I was lucky enough that second data frame was small enough to broadcast it. More precisely, I broadcasted hashmap of values but that is just because I found it suits nicely for the purpose. (see: [broadcast variables in Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables))

Then, I iterated over the rows of the first data frame like this

```
tx_df.rdd.map(my_map_function)
```

and in my_map_function I accessed broadcasted hasmap, did needed sorting and other operations and finally chose which values I want to append to the rows of the first data frame.

As a nice side-effect, of broadcasting the hashmap of values, I was able to remove the join of data frames and speed the things up.
Before doing this, script had

- loading data into data frames
- joining data frames into big one
- filtering out not needed rows of big data frame

After this broadcast solution, script has

- loading data into data frames
- broadcasting values of the second one
- iterating only over first one, directly accessing values of the second one and appending them to the current row

Filtering is not needed in the second approach because proper values are already picked up so script execution is faster.